# Code compiles and executes, but does not print anything

Tags: java

The time-limit-extended is the status when executing the successfully compiled class file of the following code.

```
import java.io.*;
public class CandidateCode {

    public static int ThirstyCrowProblem(int[] input1, int input2, int input3) {
        int[] arrK = new int[input3];
        int minstones = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input3; i++) //create an array of k Os.
        {
            int smallest = input1[0], place = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < input2; j++) {
                if ((smallest >= input1[j]) && (input1[j] >= 0)) {
                    smallest = input1[j];
                    place = j;
                }
            }
            input1[place] = -1;
            arrK[i] = smallest;
        }
        int n = input2, i = 0;
        while (i < input3)
        minstones = minstones + arrK[i] * (n - i);
        return minstones;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] {
            5, 58
        };
        int stones_min = CandidateCode.ThirstyCrowProblem(arr, 2, 1);
        System.out.println("The result is" + stones_min);
    }
}
```

The cursor is waiting and waiting, but I don't think there is an error in the code!??

Comment: you have 2 loops in your code. guess which one is infinite...

Comment: ugh. its purely a matter of style, but use brackets around your loop content, even when there's only a single statement.

Comment: @zubergu , thanks for that, but if it were not for the comment down below, i wouldn't have understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A** :
Change your while into an if statement :

```
if(i<input3) {
    minstones= minstones + arrK[i]*(n-i);
}
```

**Option B** : or increment i (i++) but I don't this that's what you want

```
while(i<input3) {
    minstones = minstones + arrK[i]*(n-i);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `i` in your while loop.Since you are not incrementing,its going in infinite loop.

```
while(i<input3)
{
    minstones= minstones + arrK[i]*(n-i);
    i++;
}
```

After making this change,I got

```
The result is10
```